# Angular Service To Set And Retrieve Object Between Controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I been trying to set an service object from a http post response to a controller and getting it from another controller.
The tutorials I seen in SO or sites are focused more on getting it from HTML input to a controller and another controller getting the value.

I would want to avoid using rootscope and I'm new to angular-js.

First Controller(To Put Data1 & Data2 in an object)

```
.controller('GetItem',function($scope, $http, $filter, $ionicPopup, $stateParams, $cordovaSQLite, $cordovaDatePicker, dataFactory){
    ...
    console.log(resp.data);
    var data1= resp.data.data1;
    var data2= resp.data.data2;
 }
```

2nd Controller (To get the object and retrieve data1 and data2)

Some pointers would be deeply appreciated!

**Update1:** (Save Function Works but Get Function Returns EMPTY):

```
.service('StoreService',function(){

 var data1=[]; //{} returns me an empty object

 this.save=function(data1){
 alert('DATA: '+ data1); //able to retrieve string
 this.data1=data1;

 };

 this.getData1=function(){
 alert('DATA1: '+ data1); //unable to get string
 return data1;

 };
})
```

This is the 2nd Controller which retrieve from service:

```
 .controller('unlock', function($scope, $timeout, dataFactory, $stateParams,StoreService) {

  function test(){
    console.log(StoreService.getData1());
```

Update 2: (Working)
Tomislav's plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/srAphQhAYuBZL18MY1Kr?p=preview

Comment: in your service you declared data1 as array. Please use var data1={} if you want only one object to save in tht variable.

Comment: Hi , both returns empty with {} returning me 'Object {}'

Comment: I've made plunker for you:  http://plnkr.co/edit/srAphQhAYuBZL18MY1Kr?p=preview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@atinder answer is way to go. Here is the example of the service:

```
app.service('StoreService',function(){

  var data1={};
  var data2={};
  this.save=function(data1,data2){        
       this.data1=data1;
       this.data2=data2;

  };

  this.getData1=function(){

    return data1;

  };

  this.getData2=function(){

    return data2;

  };
});
```

Then in first controller:

```
.controller('firstController',function(StoreService){
    .....
    StoreService.save(resp.data.data1,resp.data.data2);
 });
```

In second controller:

```
.controller('secondController',function(StoreService,$scope){
    $scope.data1 = StoreService.getData1();
    $scope.data2 = StoreService.getData2();
 });
```

Comment: Hi, i assume "StoreService.save(<Object>)"? As my resp.data return me values. And I do not understand why is there a need for '  $http.get('/your/api')' since I do not need any http request in the service. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Lemme get back to you in awhile!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark @atinder answer as correct one

Comment: Hi, console.log(StoreService.getData1()); returns me an empty object. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you use setter (save function) first?

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes and i have verified the setter works. I shall edit in my question above. Do advise thanks!

Answer (score 7):

create a basic service with setters and getters. Inject the service into both the controllers.
use setter in one controller and getter in the another.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Looking at this http://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/sk3e9e90/1/, from the service it sets the state, how do i change it to an object?