# Ionic/AngularJS: How do I save data locally from a form?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a registration form. Once the form is submitted, I just want to save the data to local storage.

Could anyone give me an example or point me to a tutorial that could help me out?

Answer (score 4):

You can use lokiJS or SQLite or even Basic Internal Get/Set.

Take a look at my question and answers:

SQLite: [Save ,retrieve and upload data to a remote server---(AngularJs / Ionic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384715/save-retrieve-and-upload-data-to-a-remote-server-angularjs-ionic/33405639#33405639)

Basic Internal Get/Set Service: 
[Angular Service To Set And Retrieve Object Between Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003749/angular-service-to-set-and-retrieve-object-between-controllers)

LokiJS(NOSQL):
http://lokijs.org/#/

http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/

LocalStorage/Session Storage :

You can also make use of existing HTML 5 local/session storage.

For just a form, you may just want to use basic internal getter/setter, that should suffice for most cases. I haven tried lokiJS personally, but i think it's good!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the GitHub Library **Angular Local Storage** in my AngularJS and Cordova/Ionic projects.

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

***Set Key in Local Storage***

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function submit(key, val) {
   return localStorageService.set(key, val);
  }
  //...
});
```

**Get Key in Local Storage**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function getItem(key) {
   return localStorageService.get(key);
  }
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $window.localStorage. For this inject $window in dependency.
Below is the syntax for this

```
$windows.localStorage["key"]=jsonValue;
```

Comment: Local storage on Ionic tend to be wiped every few days

Answer (score 0):

check this link 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html
and after submission of form inside function use local storage like ..
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/use-ngstorage-angularjs-local-storage-needs/
we need to inject ng-storage in module, inject local storage in controller/service where you want to use then store submitted data in local storage..