# Angular var used outside of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing

a simple Angular / javascript question:

I have a form which uses two functions, one is executed "on click", the other "on submit":

```
$scope.onclickevent = function(files) {
          $scope.imageFile = files[0];
          console.log($scope.imageFile);
      }

$scope.onsubmitevent = function(){
          console.log($scope.imageFile); // herein lies the problem
      }
```

The HTML is like this :

```
    <div class="file-field input-field ">
         <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onclickevent(this.files)"/>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="btn" ng-click="onsubmitevent()">Create</a>
```

How do I access $scope.imageFile from another function? Upon calling onsubmitevent, $scope.imageFile is "undefined". Yet the console.log in the first function shows it as set.

$rootscope is an option, but it seems wrong to set this globally. 
Parsing the variable back to the html and then back to the second function also seem long-winded and cumbersome.

Comment: Can you provide the html markup of your frontend ?

Comment: @VishwaKumar I have edited the question to provide the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first call `onclickevent`, it will set the `$scope.imageFile` to `files[0]`, and then you can get it from the `onsubmitevent` via `$scope.imageFile`

Comment: on calling onsubmitevent, $scope.imageFile is undefined.

Comment: @Leon if you first call `onclickevent`, you will have an value, because it assigns to the `imageFile` property of your `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

It should work after you called onclickevent.

Otherwise, you could try this:

```
$scope.onclickevent = function(files) {
      var imageFile = files[0];
      $scope.imageFile = files[0];
      console.log($scope.imageFile);
  }

$scope.onsubmitevent = function(){
      console.log(imageFile); // herein lies the problem
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use services for that

[Angular Service To Set And Retrieve Object Between Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003749/angular-service-to-set-and-retrieve-object-between-controllers)

like this

```
app.service('StoreService',function(){

  var data1={};
  var data2={};
  this.save=function(data1,data2){        
       this.data1=data1;
       this.data2=data2;

  };

  this.getData1=function(){

    return data1;

  };

  this.getData2=function(){

    return data2;

  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try initialising $scope.imageFile outside of both functions, for example:

```
$scope.imageFile = [];

$scope.onclickevent = function(files) {
      $scope.imageFile = files[0];
      console.log($scope.imageFile);
  }

$scope.onsubmitevent = function(){
      console.log($scope.imageFile);
  }
```

If this doesn't work, and I **don't reccomend this as common practice**, use a root scope variable, for example:

```
$rootScope.imageFile = [];

$scope.onclickevent = function(files) {
      $rootScope.imageFile = files[0];
      console.log($rootScope.imageFile);
  }

$scope.onsubmitevent = function(){
      console.log($rootScope.imageFile);
  }
```

I want to emphasise that using rootscope variables isn't neccessary for this; I only added it here to aid you in testing your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you can define $scope.ImageFile outside of your function

```
 $scope.imageFile = [];

 $scope.onclickevent = function(files) {
     $scope.imageFile = files[0];
     console.log($scope.imageFile);
  }

 $scope.onsubmitevent = function(){
    console.log($scope.imageFile);
 }
```